# Why does the bit flip channel produce a uniform contraction of $1-2p$?

Tags: quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, information-theory, noise

Studying the bit flip channel using the Nielsen & Chuang's.

And ran into the picture with the caption stating $yz$ plane is uniformly contracted by a factor of $1-2p$. I don't quite understand how the factor, $1-2p$, comes about and is derived.  I'd appreciate any pointers here.  Thank you!

[image]

Please refer to [Page 376, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

Comment: Parametrize state $\rho$ as $\frac{1}{2}\left( \begin{matrix}
 1+z&  x-iy\\
 x+iy&  1-z\\
\end{matrix} \right) $ and then try to let it pass through the channel with Kraus operator description.

Comment: @narip Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The operation elements corresponding to the bit flip channel are, $E_0=\sqrt{p}I=\sqrt{p}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $E_1=\sqrt{1-p}X=\sqrt{1-p}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$

And the density matrix of the initial state is, $\rho=\dfrac{I+\vec{r}.\vec{\sigma}}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+z&x-iy\\x+iy&1-z\end{bmatrix}$

The action of the bit flip channel can be defined as,

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(\rho)&=E_0\rho E_0^\dagger+E_1\rho E_1^\dagger=\rho +X\rho X\\
&=\frac{p}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+z&x-iy\\x+iy&1-z\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1-p}{2}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1+z&x-iy\\x+iy&1-z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac{p}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1+z&x-iy\\x+iy&1-z\end{bmatrix}+\frac{1-p}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1-z&x+iy\\x-iy&1+z\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}1+z(2p-1)&x-iy(2p-1)\\x+iy(2p-1)&1-z(2p-1)\end{bmatrix}\\
\sigma_x&=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\sigma_y=\begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\sigma_z=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathcal{E}(\rho)&=\frac{I+x\sigma_x+y(2p-1)\sigma_y+z(2p-1)\sigma_z}{2}=\frac{I+\vec{r}'.\vec{\sigma}}{2}\\
\end{align}
$$
\vec{r}=(x,y,z)\xrightarrow{\mathcal{E}}\vec{r}'=(x,(2p-1)y,(2p-1)z)
$$